# Why do I need a Java runtime to run XCode on Mac OS X 10.7?

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, macos

I just tried opening XCode on my Mac (10.7.1), and it required me to install Java for Mac OS X before it would run.

How come XCode needs Java?

Comment: Who knows? Who cares? :)

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I didn't have a Java runtime installed under a clean Lion installation and Xcode 4.1 installed just fine without it.

Comment: @Brad: Yeah, I had XCode already installed from before I upgraded to Lion. Maybe the latest XCode installs add it from the start. Still weird that an XCode update didn’t include it — and that Java is required at all. I thought Apple had entirely moved away from Java.